# can I declare variables with the same name in every Case branch of a Switch-Case?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a generic class object in switch case with same name I get a error for duplicate variable. Is there a way to create the object without changing the name of the object.

```
switch (ch) {
    case 1:
        Example<Integer> ex = new Example<Integer>();
        break;
    case 2:
        Example<Float> ex = new Example<Float>();
        break;
    case 3:
        Example<String> ex = new Example<String>();
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: what is the rest of your code?

Comment: what do you do after that?

Comment: Declare it outside the switch block. The scope "inside" cases is shared.

Comment: An object doesn't have a name. A variable does. What are you planning to do with such a variable later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your variable declaration outside the switch block as next:

```
Example<?> ex;
switch (ch) {
    case 1:
        ex = new Example<Integer>();
        break;
    case 2:
        ex = new Example<Float>();
        break;
    case 3:
        ex = new Example<String>();
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type " + ch);
}
```

As you mixed several types that have nothing in common, you have to use the `wildcard` for `unknown type`.

Answer (score 1):

The title of the question should be something like:
***can I declare variables with the same name in  every Case branch***
anyways...the reason of the error is because the CASE block in the Switch-case share the same scope as the whole switch block

Comment: But in this switch case I am initializing object not just declaring them.

Comment: yes, but in java this in the same as declaring it multiple times in the same scope

Answer (score 1):

You can put curly braces around the code inside each case block.
But that makes the variable local only to the case block - you can't use it out after the break.

So unless you are only going to use it inside each case, do as @dabadaba says and place it before the switch.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your duplicate variable error is because despite the fact that you declare `ex` within different case blocks, it is still technically within the same scope (i.e. a rough but simple way of putting it is they are with in the same set of `{ }`).  Put another way, imagine you removed the `break` from `case 1`; the execution would fall through to `case 2` and try to declare the variable a second time.  Since the java compiler doesn't take the `break` into account when evaluating for this sort of thing, you have a compilation error.

Fortunately, you can just declare `ex` beforehand with a wildcard and assign it value later:

```
Example<?> ex = null;
switch (ch) {
    case 1:
        ex = new Example<Integer>();
        break;
    case 2:
        ex = new Example<Float>();
        break;
    case 3:
        ex = new Example<String>();
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println(""); //You may want to do something more dramatic here, if this is an error case.
        break; //Redundant, since execution path falls out of this scope right after this anyway.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think In Java,
the pair of curly braces i.e. {} confines the scope. A variable declared between { and }, starts its scope from the declaration statement to the respective closing brace of starting brace.
For exa.
Let say {- start and }- close
Now,

start1
var A borns here
start2
var B borns here!

```
   var B can not live further this!
 close2
```

var A can leave upto here!
close1

---

I hope, I dictate it well!!